# Is $\frac{ \mathbb{C}[x,y] }{\langle x^m+ y^n -1\rangle} \cong \ \frac{ \mathbb{C}[y]}{\langle y^n-1\rangle }$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Today I saw an isomorphism in my friends notebook. It was written as $$\frac{ \mathbb{C}[x,y] }{\langle x^m+ y^n -1\rangle} \cong \ \frac{ \mathbb{C}[y]}{\langle y^n-1\rangle }.$$

I want to confirm that it is true/false. I'm very confused as to how to do this.
Any hints about a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The residue class ring ${\Bbb C}[y]/\langle y^n-1\rangle$ has the ${\Bbb C}$-basis $\{1+I,y+I,\ldots,y^{n-1}+I\}$, where $I=\langle y^n-1\rangle$.

The situation is different for  the residue class ring ${\Bbb C}[x,y]/\langle x^m+y^n-1\rangle$. Put $J=\langle x^m+y^n-1\rangle$. Here you have $x^m+J = (-y^n+1)+J$. So each power of $x^k$ with $k\geq m$ can be replaced by an expression in $y$. Up to the trivial case, the  ${\Bbb C}$-basis of the residue class ring is definitely larger. Construct the basis...